# Beach Cleaning Robot - Wheel Slip problem

Tags: control, motor

I am building a beach cleaning robot. I am having problems with it moving on the Sand. I have attached a video of it struggling to move. How can I proceed (I think it has enough torque) . it moves comfortably on normal ground. Do I need diff wheels, motors, wheel size etc? [Video of slippage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Ri1gwZjr9c&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 2):

I'd consider using tracks on your robot. Your video shows the very reason why the military use tracks on vehicles intended for operation on sand.

In fact, you can see one example of a beach cleaning robot from DronyX. They use their tracked vehicle for their Solaryno [beach cleaning robot](http://www.dronyx.com/solarino-beach-cleaner/).

Of course, that is just one example of a beach cleaning robot. [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=beach%20cleaning%20robot&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_r5DpurvWAhWhK8AKHXsKAbYQ_AUICygC&biw=1527&bih=845) will show you plenty of others, and a majority seem to use tracked propulsion.